# ActionScript 3.0 how to define custom operators?

Tags: actionscript-3, operators

How can I define a custom operator - for example equality operator - for a custom class?

Comment: Are you talking about operator overloding? AS3 doesn't allow for it. You'd have to create a custom method instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native operator overloading in ActionScript.

You might want to check out [this](http://lab.polygonal.de/2006/08/29/operator-overloading/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007/lack-of-operator-overloading-in-actionscript-3-0).